# JSON deserialize property including $

Tags: java, json, jackson

Having a JSON with a property like this which i try to deserialze with jackson:

```
 { "$fooid" : "yfdfjjhkjhkljhd768622323jjj" }
```

Problem here is, i'm not able to read the key "$fooid".

I tried to annotate the property with

```
@JsonAlias("$fooid")
private String fooid;
```

also as

```
@JsonProperty("$fooid")
private String fooid;
```

Both variants won't work, the property fooid is always null.

How to deserialize it in Java? Any hints?

Comment: Did you try putting the annotation on the getter/setter (have a look at the documentation) and make sure that the packages match? (We sometimes have the problem with Jackson 1.x annotations vs. Jackson 2.x at runtime.)

Comment: both works for me too with Jackson 2.9.6

Comment: how are you reading this json? because when I try to deserialize     `String json="{ \"$fooid\" : \"yfdfjjhkjhkljhd768622323jjj\" }" `; it works for me using version 2.0.0 do you have also a getter and a setter for fooid?

Comment: Hmm, i'm using jackson 2.9.6 as well but it won't work for me. @kukkuz Can you you provide your solution? Im using GSON as generator. May be this can be the problem?

Comment: `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

class Hello {

    @JsonAlias("$fooid")
    private String fooid;

    public String getFooid() {
        return fooid;
    }

    public void setFooid(String fooid) {
        this.fooid = fooid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Hello hello = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"$fooid\" : \"yfdfjjhkjhkljhd768622323jjj\" }", Hello.class);
        System.out.println(hello.getFooid());
    }
}`

Comment: @kukuzz, thanks a lot. I tried it as you provid and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how are you doing It, but It is working for me on version 2.0.0 doing this.

```
public class JSonAliasWithSpecialCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json="{ \"$fooid\" : \"yfdfjjhkjhkljhd768622323jjj\" }";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFooid fooid = mapper.readValue(json, JsonFooid.class);
        System.out.println("read the foodid:"+fooid.getFooid());
    }

}

public class JsonFooid {

    @JsonProperty("$fooid")
    private String fooid;

    public String getFooid() {
        return fooid;
    }

    public void setFooid(String fooid) {
        this.fooid = fooid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Jap, with this solution i get the JSON deserialized. I guess GSON is the problem in my chain. Thanks to @vmrvictor.